# cakePHP set Cookies for SameSite Attribute. But I can't find it in the Code/track it down

Tags: cakephp, cookies, tracking, samesite

I'm still becoming a developer. First of all I can't show any code related to this problem because I'm not allowed to do so...

With the new cookie policy from Chrome (and others) the `SameSite` attribute must be set to None.

My problem is, that I can't find any code where the cookies are set. It comes from a server. I searched the git repositories of the company I'm currently at. 
I searched the internet for every solution possible. The problem is finding the right place to put it in. The code is written in php which I haven't learned so far.

The said cookie comes from another website and I unable track it down.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? CakePHP 2 has Session Cookies defined in `App/Config/core.php`.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained You should set a `SameSite` value for your cookies, but `SameSite=None; Secure` is **only** required if you need cookies available in a third-party / cross-site context. If the cookies are only intended for visitors on your site, you should be looking at `SameSite=Lax` or `SameSite=Strict`.

Comment: Well the code is really weird (not mine obviously). So there is no folder containing the cookie creation.

And I get the warning on the site with the 'SameSite' attribute. It seems that the server ('cdn') is sending it to the website and the error occurs

Comment: `It seems that the server ('cdn') is sending it to the website` - what does this mean? Maybe you should back up a bit - how do you know your site sets cookies? What CDN are you referring to? [PHP uses `setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to set cookies, so if you grep your sources for that you will find wherever CakePHP does that.

Answer (score 4):

Cake 3.5.8

In your config/app.php add the following lines into the Session['ini'] section:

```
'Session' => [
        'ini' => [
           'session.cookie_samesite' => 'None',
           'session.cookie_secure' => true
       ]
],
```

Comment: Perfect !  Just be sure to always use httpS after that https://stackoverflow.com/a/28386688/2152973

Answer (score 0):

I am using cakephp 1.3. I need backend cookie at front-end that is not same domain. As of other solution not worked then I use my code.
I created new cookie after login. Then, on front-end I used this cookie as backend login check and done my stuf.

```
header("Set-Cookie: admin_login= ".$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id']."; path=/; ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to hack this using the following in CakePHP 3.8.13 and PHP 7.2

```
    $this->Cookie->setConfig([
        'path' =>  '/; SameSite=Lax',
        'expires' => '+180 days',
        'httpOnly' => \FALSE
    ]);
```