# How to tell PHP to use SameSite=None for cross-site cookies?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, php-7.3

According to the article here https://php.watch/articles/PHP-Samesite-cookies and PHP documenation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.ini.php, There are only 2 possible config options for this new feature, added in PHP 7.3:

1. session.cookie_samesite=Lax
2. session.cookie_samesite=Strict

Yet, according to the Chrome console, this needs to be set to "None":

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at URL was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at URL and URL.

Because of this, I can no longer set cross-site cookies. What is the workaround?

Comment: you can check here with php header.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63481019/6128573

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can set the value to "None" using [`ini_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php). There's no check that the value is supported when that function is used:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
session_start();
```

[`session_set_cookie_params`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) can also set it:

```
session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'None']);
session_start();
```

The bug report for this to be supported in php.ini is [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78651).

---

As [@shrimpwagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78615/shrimpwagon) said in a [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534999/how-to-tell-php-to-use-samesite-none-for-cross-site-cookies/59535165#comment112878599_59535165), `session.cookie_secure` must be `true` for this to work. PHP doesn't require it, but browsers do.

Comment: Thank you - I was able to use the following code to get rid of the Chrome message and allow cross-site cookies to continue working: 

session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'None', 'secure' => true]);

Comment: beware, samesite=none is not supported in old browsers and will reject the cookie completely. check this and make sure to exclude old browsers when setting a samesite attribute to your session cookie: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients

Comment: Setting session.cookie_samesite=None in the php.ini did NOT work in PHP 7.3.15.  Using session_set_cookie_params as described above did work.

Comment: Slightly incorrect. Needs to be:
`session_set_cookie_params(['SameSite' => 'None', 'Secure' => true]);`

Comment: @shrimpwagon Updated

Answer (score 9):

`ini_set('session.cookie_secure', "1"); ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', "1"); ini_set('session.cookie_samesite','None'); session_start();`

php 7.4 samesite in phpinfo
[image]

php 7.2 samesite does not exist in phpinfo
[image]

```
$currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
$cookie_domain= 'your domain';
if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70300) {
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' =>  $currentCookieParams["lifetime"],
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => $cookie_domain,
    'secure' => "1",
    'httponly' => "1",
    'samesite' => 'None',
]);
} else {
session_set_cookie_params(
    $currentCookieParams["lifetime"],
    '/; samesite=None',
    $cookie_domain,
    "1",
    "1"
);
}
session_start();
```

Answer (score 4):

Bad:

```
session.cookie_samesite=None
```

Correct:

```
session.cookie_samesite="None"
```

Explanation [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/c00cce3229515eacdb1680f39132ed3ca09cc205)

Comment: Don't do this. Some browsers are bugged and will reject cookies altogether with SameSite=None. You need to sniff the UserAgent first. [Here is an explanation from Google](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients).

Answer (score 0):

This method can be helpful for u

Add header's attributes on `nginx` below `Secure` + `SameSite=None`

> location / {
>
> proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; SameSite=none";
>
> }

It's working on me!

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5.6.40, there exists a workaround (the hack on path parameter) which does not involve rebuilding PHP.

If you have no problem rebuilding the PHP binary, I managed to port this feature from PHP 7.3 to PHP 5.6.40, and there is now a pull request.
I needed it for our projects that aren't migrated yet.
I know 5.6 branch is deprecated, I am just sharing.

Pull request:
https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/6446

Our repo with the changes:
https://github.com/Inducido/php-src/tree/PHP-5.6.40

Build tested on Debian 8.11

## New Feature

Session:
. Added support for the SameSite cookie directive for setcookie(),
setrawcookie() and session_set_cookie_params().
Port from PHP 7.x branch
they all have an "samesite" additionnal parameter at the very end (string)

prototypes:

```
bool setcookie(string name [, string value [, int expires [, string path [, string domain [, bool secure[, bool httponly[, string samesite]]]]]]])
bool setrawcookie(string name [, string value [, int expires [, string path [, string domain [, bool secure[, bool httponly[, string samesite]]]]]]])
void session_set_cookie_params(int lifetime [, string path [, string domain [, bool secure[, bool httponly[, string samesite]]]]])
(session_get_cookie_params updated too)
```

## Changes to INI File Handling

- session.cookie_samesite
  . New INI option to allow to set the SameSite directive for cookies. Defaults
  to "" (empty string), so no SameSite directive is set. Can be set to "Lax"
  or "Strict", or "None" which sets the respective SameSite directive.
  when using "None", make sure to include the quotes, as `none` is interpreted
  like `false` in ini files.

This solves the issue "This Set-Cookie was blocked due to user preferences" in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you use nginx, you can also modify the cookie using lua. It is a bit hacky, but I found it to be working well for legacy sites:

```
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;

            # This is the relevant part:
            header_filter_by_lua '
                    local cookies = ngx.header.set_cookie
                    if cookies then
                            if type(cookies) ~= "table" then
                                    cookies = {cookies}
                            end
                            local gsub = string.gsub
                            local changed
                            for i, cookie in ipairs(cookies) do
                                    local new_cookie = gsub(cookie, "^PHPSESSION=(.*)", "PHPSESSION=%1; Samesite=strict", 1)
                                    if new_cookie ~= cookie then
                                            cookies[i] = new_cookie
                                            changed = true
                                    end
                            end
                            if changed then
                                    ngx.header.set_cookie = cookies
                            end
                    end
            ';
            # End Lua
    }
```

You might need to adapt the regex (gsub), but I found it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Mission:
let JS Ajax request be done from another domain (e,g: localhost)

steps:

A. add `withCredentials` to your ajax request

B. set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` among the rest of the `Access-Control-Allow-...` headers

C. add `"samesite" => "none"` to your session cookie params.

finally my code look like this:

Server:

```
$currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params([
    "lifetime" => $currentCookieParams["lifetime"],
    "path" => $currentCookieParams["path"],
    "domain" => $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],
    "secure" => true,
    "samesite" => "none",
    "httponly" => $currentCookieParams["httponly"]
]);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"]);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD"]);
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

js - client:

```
fetch(`https://example.com/login.php`, {
    method: 'POST',
    withCredentials: true,
    body: `username=${user}&password=${pass}`
 }).then(res => {
     if (res.status === 200) {




        //here session cookie exists and sent to server, so i can access the data
        fetch(`https://example.com/secret.php`, {
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                console.log(res.body);
            } else {
                console.error("error")
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })



    } else {
        console.error("error")
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

tested with FF 112 and Chromium 113 on ubuntu